# point-plane distance in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I was trying to calculate the point-plane distance from point (x_1, y_1, z_1) to the plane ax+by+cz+d=0 in SymPy, but I found the result incorrect. The following is the code I use

```py
from sympy import *

a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')
x1, y1, z1 = symbols('x_1 y_1 z_1')

p1 = Point(x1, y1, z1)
plane1 = Plane(Point(0, 0, -d/c), normal_vector=(a, b, c))

plane1.distance(p1)
```

The correct answer should be \frac{ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}

But SymPy gives me \frac{ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. [Here](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/geometry/plane.html) is how sympy calculates the distance (method `distance(self, o)`):

```py
self = plane1
o = p1

x, y, z = map(Dummy, 'xyz')
k = self.equation(x, y, z)
a, b, c = [k.coeff(i) for i in (x, y, z)]
d = k.xreplace({x: o.args[0], y: o.args[1], z: o.args[2]})
t = abs(d/sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2))
```

If we inspect `k` and `a, b, c` we see that the equation's coefficients are not correct:

```py
print(k)
print(a, b, c)

# output:
_x*a + _y*b + c*(_z + d/c)
a b 0
```

`c` is zero, which explains your result. This can be fixed by simplifying the equation:

```
k = simplify(self.equation(x, y, z))
```

in which case the distance `t` is as you expected it:

```
print(t)
# output
Abs((a*x_1 + b*y_1 + c*z_1 + d)/sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2))
```

**Update**: This was fixed in the current master of SymPy. See the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18027).